# Global evaluation not supported on dart in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart

[Input is not printed out.Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnmT6.png)

The same code works properly when run in terminal using dart command. So I think it is mostly because I am running in debug console but running in the terminal is tiresome. What is the problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception "Global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded" on VSCode when reading values with Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71946458/exception-global-evaluation-requires-a-thread-to-have-been-loaded-on-vscode-wh)

Answer (score 2):

We don't currently support evaluating expressions in Dart Code when you're not stopped at a breakpoint. There is an open issue about this here:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/906

Please  the issue if it's important to you and hopefully it can be added in an upcoming update.

Comment: it would be great if you add that :)

Comment: Subscribe to that issue on GH for notifications of when it gets done; but assuming the required APIs are there to support it (from the Dart side), I'm hoping it won't be a big job :-)

Comment: @DannyTuppeny any progress on that?

Comment: @DenisSablukov Afraid not - I did start a branch to try it, but it turned out to be much more complicated than I expected - the VM wants to know the scope to evaluate it (eg. so it knows which top-level symbols exist) which means the debugger needs to know which file you have open (which it doesn't, because it can run in a separate process). I will get back to it at some point, it's just been back-burner'd a little bit because of the effort :-)