# global evaluation is not supported on Vscode when use shift+r flutter

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, flutter, vscode-debugger

When I use hot reload on my debug console it says "global evaluation not supported". How do I fix this problem?

Before I read this [global evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548663/global-evaluation-not-supported-on-dart-in-vscode), but it did not help me

This is the image of my [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0lgd.jpg)

Comment: Can you try running `flutter run` directly on the command line to see if that works? And make sure that when you run `flutter doctor -v` that you don't get any warnings or errors...

Answer (score 7):

Add configuration `"console":"terminal"` in launch.json

**Example:**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "dart_application_1",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "bin/dart_application_1.dart",
            "console": "terminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

More details available [here](https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-9/#dart-cli-terminal-improvements)

Comment: Hi,on generating the Dart(2.12.0-141.0.dev) template 'SimpleConsoleApplication' from command palette ,didn't create the launch.json file in dart tools (only package_config.json created).Which template did you use?Thanks.

Comment: If you click on run and debug on the left side of VS Code, it will propose you to create the json file. Otherwise you can create manually the file launch.json it has to be in a folder .vscode in the root of your project.

Answer (score 3):

The VS Code debugger for Dart/Flutter does not currently support global evaluation (there's an open issue for this [here](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/906)). Add a  to that issue if it's something you'd like to see.

The debug console *can* be used for evaluation when execution is paused (eg. you've stopped at a breakpoint or similar) - this is evaluation in the context of the current frame.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember to update your name to your project name and then again on the program setting AFTER the bin/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal in VS Code. In case you are unable to open up the terminal, follow the following steps.

> Search for "Terminal" at the top bar of VS Code page.
> Click the terminal and click on "Run Active File".
> Write dart [your file name.dart] (ignore square brackets) and press enter.

Now you can give input while running the dart program

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the debugger write the following command on your console:

```
dart run
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Dart extension, you can just open settings in vs code, search for dart console, then choose terminal.

[image: settings screenshot]